# Python Loading Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, loading

I am trying to make a loading text like in games loading screens!
Just like this:
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
but print it in the same line. I managed to do that but I can't figure out how to make it restart!
Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code!

```
import time


def loading():
    a = ('Loading')
    for i in range(4):
        i = ('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        a = a + i
        if(len(a) <= len('Loading...')):
            print(a, end='\r')
        else:
            return loading()
loading()
```

Comment: did you think of clearing the terminal or whatever you're using to display data?

Comment: @ElSheikh no i didnt and thank you i just added 2 lines and it works oof

Comment: okay perfect, happy that it helped

Comment: @PanicKk, you can apply some features of python: `for i in range(4): print("Loading" + "." * (i + 1), end="\r")`

Answer (score 0):

I just added 2 lines and it works! Thanks @ElSheikh for the idea :)

```
import time
import os

def loading():
    a = ('Loading')
    for i in range(4):
        i = ('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        a = a + i
        if(len(a) <= len('Loading...')):
            print(a, end='\r')
        else:
            os.system('cls')
            return loading()
loading()
```

Comment: You could also just change out `os.system('cls')` with something like `print('Loading    ', end='\r')`. That way you'd maintain your line position.

Comment: @Axe319 ahh this is better